# Should a property be in an abstract class if not directly used

Tags: object-oriented-design, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class that is inherited by several different other types. They were all using a type injected into their constructor. So I moved this property in to the abstract base class. The base class doesn't use it in any of it's methods. It is used in every single one of the inheriting classes though. Should this be in the base class or declared separately in the other classes?

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    protected TypeA a {get;}

    protected FooBase(TypeA a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class FooA : FooBase
{
    public FooA(TypeA a) : base (a)
    {
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        a.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this.

The fact that it is an abstract class in of itself means it is missing components.  Sometimes these components are instruction while other components are data.  This would simply be an example of an abstract class missing instruction.

You're simply establishing that all classes which derive from your base class must provide a TypeA instance in some shape or form.

However this said, it would be *incorrect* for any derived classes not to use this instance.  If you find yourself in this situation, you should re-evaluate the relationship between your classes.  The place to put classes which don't require TypeA is *above* your abstract base class, not below it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is it depends ...

Is TypeA specific to FooA, or might there be additional implementations e.g.

```
public class FooB : FooBase
{
}
```

which also reference the TypeA property?

In general, properties / methods should be declared in a common parent class, rather than multiple times in descendents, but a parent class should only contain elements required by all of its children.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one important point of having base classes is to reduce duplication. The point that the base class doesn't actually use  a field or method doesn't count against it - technically, if a base class is abstract, it doesn't *actually* use *any* of its functionality, but that doesn't mean that abstract classes aren't useful.